# How to open a RTP packet containing video in Java?

Tags: java, rtp

I have VLC streaming a TS file using RTP protocol. How do I use java to receive the packet and open it?

What I want to do is provide the URL and I need the TS payload from the stream, packet by packet.

I have a module which can playback TS stream, I need a way to receive the RTP and give the TS to the playback module.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'open it'? Do you want to read parameters from it? Do you want the byte values of the pixels? Do you want to display it? Do you want this for a single packet or the whole stream (packet by packet)?

Comment: @Shel Thanks, updated the question.